# How to monitor success or failure of attempts to modify security settings or permissions in GAE?

Tags: audit, google-app-engine

In AWS I can use CloudTrail to monitor API calls that may impact IAM groups and roles.

In Google App Engine, is there any similar offering like CloudTrail? In Google Cloud Platform, as far as I can see, the 'IAM & Admin' panel only allows management and display of basic info IAM  user and service accounts. The slack driver also does not seem to offer audit trail (The feature is currently in private beta and is not recommended for production use: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control).

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud offers [Cloud Audit Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) which is used to record and log user interactions with your [Google Cloud project and resources](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#services).

You can easily access audit logs either directly from the [Activity Feed](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity), or from the [Stackdriver Logging Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) by selecting 'activity' in the resource drop-down menu.

If you are instead looking for additional functionality, you can submit a feature request using one of the appropriate [Google Public Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).